# Simulating expectation of continuous random variable

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, simulation, distribution

Currently I want to generate some samples to get expectation & variance of it.

Given the probability density function: f(x) = {2x, 0 <= x <= 1; 0 otherwise}

I already found that E(X) = 2/3, Var(X) = 1/18, my detail solution is from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4430163/simulating-expectation-of-continuous-random-variable

But here is what I have when simulating using python:

```py
import numpy as np
N = 100_000
X = np.random.uniform(size=N, low=0, high=1)
Y = [2*x for x in X]
np.mean(Y) # 1.00221 <- not equal to 2/3
np.var(Y) # 0.3323 <- not equal to 1/18
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if it answers your question!

Comment: thank you @oda for your detail answer!!

Comment: Happy I can help @Hoang Ngo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To approximate the integral of some function of `x`, say, `g(x)`, over `S = [0, 1]`, using Monte Carlo simulation, you

- generate `N` random numbers in `[0, 1]` (i.e. draw from the uniform distribution `U[0, 1]`)
- calculate the arithmetic mean of `g(x_i)` over `i = 1` to `i = N` where `x_i` is the `i`th random number: i.e. `(1 / N)` times the sum from `i = 1` to `i = N` of `g(x_i)`.

The result of step 2 is the approximation of the integral.

The expected value of continuous random variable `X` with pdf `f(x)` and set of possible values `S` is the integral of `x * f(x)` over `S`. The variance of `X` is the expected value of `X`-squared minus the square of the expected value of `X`.

- **Expected value**: to approximate the integral of `x * f(x)` over `S = [0, 1]` (i.e. the **expected value** of `X`), set `g(x) = x * f(x)` and apply the method outlined above.
- **Variance**: to approximate the integral of `(x * x) * f(x)` over `S = [0, 1]` (i.e. the **expected value** of `X`-squared), set `g(x) = (x * x) * f(x)` and apply the method outlined above. Subtract the result of this by the square of the estimate of the expected value of `X` to obtain an estimate of the **variance** of `X`.

Adapting your method:

```
import numpy as np
N = 100_000
X = np.random.uniform(size = N, low = 0, high = 1)

Y = [x * (2 * x) for x in X]
E = [(x * x) * (2 * x) for x in X]

# mean
print((a := np.mean(Y)))
# variance 
print(np.mean(E) - a * a)
```

Output

```
0.6662016482614397
0.05554821798023696
```

Instead of making `Y` and `E` lists, a much better approach is

```
Y = X * (2 * X)
E = (X * X) * (2 * X)
```

`Y`, `E` in this case are `numpy` arrays. This approach is **much more** efficient. Try making `N = 100_000_000` and compare the execution times of both methods. The second should be much faster.

Answer (score 4):

You are generating the mean and variance of Y = 2X, when you want the mean and variance of the X's themselves. You know the density, but the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) is more useful for random variate generation than the [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). For your problem, the density is:

[image: f(x) = 2x]

so the CDF is:

[image: F(x) = x**2]

Given that the CDF is an easily invertible function for the range [0,1], you can use [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to generate X values by setting F(X) = U, where U is a Uniform(0,1) random variable, and inverting the relationship to solve for X. For your problem, this yields X = U<sup>1/2</sup>.

In other words, you can generate X values with

```python
import numpy as np
N = 100_000
X = np.sqrt(np.random.uniform(size = N))
```

and then do anything you want with the data, such as calculate mean and variance, plot histograms, use in simulation models, or whatever.

A histogram will confirm that the generated data have the desired density:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(X, bins = 100, density = True)
plt.show()
```

produces
[image: Histogram of the generated data, plotted as density]

The mean and variance estimates can then be calculated directly from the data:

```
print(np.mean(X), np.var(X))     # => 0.6661509538922444 0.05556962913014367
```

---

## But wait!  There’s more...

---

### Margin of error

Simulation generates random data, so estimates of mean and variance will be variable across repeated runs.  Statisticians use [confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) to quantify the magnitude of the uncertainty in statistical estimates. When the sample size is sufficiently large to invoke the central limit theorem, an interval estimate of the mean is calculated as (x-bar ± half-width), where x-bar is the estimate of the mean.  For a so-called 95% confidence interval, the half-width is `1.96 * s / sqrt(n)` where:

- `s` is the estimated standard deviation;
- `n` is the number of samples used in the estimates of mean and standard deviation; and
- 1.96 is a scaling constant derived from the normal distribution and the desired level of confidence.

The half-width is a quantitative measure of the margin of error, a.k.a. precision, of the estimate. Note that as `n` gets larger, the estimate has a smaller margin of error and becomes more precise, but there are diminishing returns to increasing the sample size due to the square root. Increasing the precision by a factor of 2 would require 4 times the sample size if independent sampling is used.

In Python:

```python
var = np.var(X)
print(np.mean(X), var, 1.96 * np.sqrt(var / N))
```

produces results such as

```
0.6666763186360812 0.05511848269208021 0.0014551397290634852
```

where the third column is the confidence interval half-width.

### Improving precision

Inverse transform sampling can yield greater precision for a given sample size if we use a clever trick based on fundamental properties of expectation and variance. In intro prob/stats courses you probably were told that `Var(X + Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y)`. The true relationship is actually `Var(X + Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2Cov(X,Y)`, where `Cov(X,Y)` is the [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) between `X` and `Y`. If they are independent, the covariance is 0 and the general relationship becomes the one we learn/teach in intro courses, but if they are not independent the more general equation must be used. Variance is always a positive quantity, but covariance can be either positive or negative. Consequently, it’s easy to see that if `X` and `Y` have negative covariance the variance of their sum will be less than when they are independent. Negative covariance means that when `X` is above its mean `Y` tends to be below its mean, and vice-versa.

So how does that help? It helps because we can use the inverse transform, along with a technique known as [antithetic variates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithetic_variates), to create pairs of random variables which are identically distributed but have negative covariance. If *U* is a random variable with a Uniform(0,1) distribution, *U’ = 1 - U* also has a Uniform(0,1) distribution. (In fact, flipping any symmetric distribution will produce the same distribution.) As a result, *X = F<sup>-1</sup>(U)* and *X’ = F<sup>-1</sup>(U’)* are identically distributed since they’re defined by the same CDF, but will have negative covariance because they fall on opposite sides of their shared median and thus strongly tend to fall on opposite sides of their mean. If we average each pair to get *A = (F<sup>-1</sup>(u<sub>i</sub>) + F<sup>-1</sup>(1-u<sub>i</sub>)) / 2)* the expected value E[*A*] = E[(*X + X’)/2*] = 2E[*X*]/2 = E[X] while the variance Var(*A*) = [(Var(*X*) + Var(*X’*) + 2Cov(*X,X’*)]/4 = 2[Var(*X*) + Cov(*X,X’*)]/4 = [Var(*X*) + Cov(*X,X’*)]/2. In other words, we get a random variable *A* whose average is an unbiased estimate of the mean of *X* but which has less variance.

To fairly compare antithetic results head-to-head with independent sampling, we take the original sample size and allocate it with half the data being generated by the inverse transform of the *U*’s, and the other half generated by antithetic pairing using *1-U*’s.  We then average the paired values and generate statistics as before. In Python:

```python
U = np.random.uniform(size = N // 2)
antithetic_avg = (np.sqrt(U) + np.sqrt(1.0 - U)) / 2
anti_var = np.var(antithetic_avg)
print(np.mean(antithetic_avg), anti_var, 1.96*np.sqrt(anti_var / (N / 2)))
```

which produces results such as

```
0.6667222935263972 0.0018911848781598295 0.0003811869837216061
```

Note that the half-width produced with independent sampling is nearly 4 times as large as the half-width produced using antithetic variates.  To put it another way, we would need more than an order of magnitude more data for independent sampling to achieve the same precision.

Answer (score 2):

In the past few years, nice new tools have been added to SciPy to address this kind of problem.
You can easily generate samples from custom continuous or discrete univariate distributions by just providing some information about the distribution, such as the density / pdf.

Overview of the different methods:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.sampling.html

Tutorial:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/sampling.html

In your concrete example, you can do the following:

```
from scipy.stats import sampling


class MyDist:
    def pdf(self, x):
        return 2*x
    
    def support(self):
        return 0, 1
    
dist = MyDist()
gen = sampling.NumericalInversePolynomial(dist)

x = gen.rvs(size=100_000)
x.mean()
```

Note that this also work in case you have more complicated densities where you cannot easiy compute the CDF and its inverse.